# Pandas sorting in Multi index dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe, in the example the index is Salesperson, year, quarter, Car model.
I'd like to sort within each quarter and for every quarter so that the car model with the most number of units sold comes first.

For Tom, 2022, Q1 the end result would be Benz top, Audi middle and Ford bottom. How do I do this pls?

```
cars_sold = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    ['Tom','Jerry'],
    ['2022', '2023'],
    ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
    ['Ford', 'Audi', 'Benz']])
columns = ['units sold']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(48).reshape((len(cars_sold), len(columns))),
    index=cars_sold,
    columns=columns)
```

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify the example code: `df = pd.DataFrame({'units sold': range(48)}, index=cars_sold)`. Or `range(len(cars_sold))`

Comment: It'd help to put a more specific title, say "How can I sort values relative to part of the MultiIndex?" See [ask] for tips on that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to add the `units sold` column to the index, sort the index on all levels except the model and then reset `units sold` to a column again:

```
df = (df
    .set_index('units sold', append=True)
    .sort_index(level=[0,1,2,'units sold'], ascending=[True,True,True,False])
    .reset_index('units sold')
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
                    units sold
Jerry 2022 Q1 Benz          26
              Audi          25
              Ford          24
           Q2 Benz          29
              Audi          28
              Ford          27
...
           Q4 Benz          47
              Audi          46
              Ford          45
Tom   2022 Q1 Benz           2
              Audi           1
              Ford           0
...
           Q3 Benz          20
              Audi          19
              Ford          18
           Q4 Benz          23
              Audi          22
              Ford          21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [groupby `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html), though it might not be super fast.

I also added names to the index so it's easier to understand.

```
(
    df.groupby(
        level=df.index.names.difference(['Car model']),
        as_index=False,
        sort=False)
    .apply(lambda d: d.sort_values('units sold', ascending=False))
    .droplevel(0)  # Remove numeric index
)
```

```
                                    units sold
Salesperson year quarter Car model            
Tom         2022 Q1      Benz                2
                         Audi                1
                         Ford                0
...                                        ...
Jerry       2023 Q4      Benz               47
                         Audi               46
                         Ford               45

[48 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add names to the index, you can use [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). This is like [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77876789/4518341) but simpler.

```
df.sort_values(
    ['Salesperson', 'year', 'quarter', 'units sold'],
    ascending=[True, True, True, False])
```

```
                                    units sold
Salesperson year quarter Car model            
Jerry       2022 Q1      Benz               26
                         Audi               25
                         Ford               24
...                                        ...
Tom         2023 Q4      Benz               23
                         Audi               22
                         Ford               21

[48 rows x 1 columns]
```